# Grep for a file that matches the pattern and file above it in a directory using grep

Tags: grep

How can I grep for a file in a directory which matches the content and line just above it?

For example:

I have below files in directory

```
abc

***bbc***

**ftd**

ctd

###ls -ltr | grep -i ftd
```

Output should return both **ftp** and **bbc**.

I am using Solaris 10 on my machine.

I cannot install any additional packages on my machine.

Comment: ftp sure not ftd?

Comment: Yeah... it should be ftd

Comment: does your `grep` have the `-B` option? if it is available, `ls -ltr | grep -B 1 -i ftd`

Answer (score 2):

All good advice about not parsing the output of `ls` aside, this may do what you want for your specific case:

```
ls -tr | awk '/^ftd$/{print prev ORS $0} {prev=$0}'
```

Oh, and on Solaris the default awk in /bin is old, broken awk which must never be used. Use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead.